# Satisfiability solvers in games

Tags: artificial-intelligence, sat

Have SAT or SMT solvers been used in video games for AI? What tasks have been solved with them? Almost all I can find is related to puzzles.

Comment: They are heavily used in formal-verification and processor-design. The last paper i read involving SAT used them to generate examples for voting-paradox cases (no-show paradox). I'm pretty sure you will be able to find some survey which lists potential and real-world applications.

Comment: Another area where they are used heavily is AI planning. AFAIK, the fastest planning algorithms are currently relying on a solution to 3SAT, despite that fact that the classical AI problem is PSpace-complete and 3SAT only NP-complete. SAT solvers are so well implemented these days that the additional exponent in the problem translation does not 'hurt'. Papers are easy to find and applications reach far beyond puzzles. (Question might raise more interest in Computer Science though...)